# Pydantic model list with variable size and typed list/typle

Tags: pydantic

I'd like to make a Model for an API that accepts a list of json objects. The payload looks like:

`[{"header": "pets"}, {"meows": true}, {"barks": false}, {"meows": true}]`

In fake pseudo code the type would be [Header, Pet, ...] where Pet can repeat. I can't figure out a good way to model this in Pydantic. Tuple would support Header, Pet but not allow the repeating Pet. `list[Union[Header, Pet]]` is what I'm using with RootModel, but requires a lot of manual and tedious validation. If I could remove Header from the Union smart or left_to_right picking logic it would be easier. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you can customize a class method to construct a model instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the model to base from `RootModel[list]`? If not, how about this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator

class Pet(BaseModel):
    meows: bool | None = None
    barks: bool | None = None

class Header(BaseModel):
    header: str

class Model(BaseModel):
    header: Header
    pets: list[Pet]

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: list[dict]) -> dict:
        return {"header": data[0], "pets": data[1:]}

data = [{"header": "pets"}, {"meows": True}, {"barks": True}, {"meows": True}]
m = Model.model_validate(data)
print(m)
print(m.model_dump())
```

Output:

```
header=Header(header='pets') pets=[Pet(meows=True, barks=None), Pet(meows=None, barks=True), Pet(meows=True, barks=None)]
{'header': {'header': 'pets'}, 'pets': [{'meows': True, 'barks': None}, {'meows': None, 'barks': True}, {'meows': True, 'barks': None}]}
```